# Change appearance of Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, themes

I wanted to create a personal theme for Chrome.
and would like to know where i can edit/change the outlines, borders for the tabs, search bar etc.

I pretty much want to remove them all to give a more minimal ui.

Thanks

Im on OSX lion by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try one of these online tools:

- http://www.chromethememaker.com/
- http://www.chrometheme.net/chrome-theme-creator-online.html

Comment: Thanks tried this and it still kept the default ui shadows etc. 
I think its impossible :) thanks though :)